# Find out the HOST IP of a VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, ip

I have the following setup: I have a linux host, running a brunch of windows virtual machines (VMware) and I log in to one of those VMs via logmein. I need to get a file from the HOST machine (the linux one on which the windows VM runs) but I don't know its IP... Is there a way to find out the IP of the host from this configuration?

Thanks, f.

Comment: Which network configuration is set in VMware: NAT, bridge or host only?

Comment: bridge is set there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded and run an IP scanner application which prints out the IP and the host name, so this way I have found out the IP of the host.